# How to resolve blocking problems that are caused by DELETE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

Why below delete T-SQL create blocking and taking long time to run?

```
declare @StartDate date 
declare @EndDate date 

set @StartDate='08/01/2016'
set @EndDate='12/30/2016' 

WHILE @StartDate<= @EndDate 
BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        print ' Clean up date ' + convert(varchar, @StartDate, 101)

        DELETE FROM [SAMPLEDB].[dbo].[MYTABLE]  
        WHERE CONVERT(DATE, CREATE_DATE, 101) = @StartDate 

        COMMIT TRANSACTION  

        SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @StartDate);
 END
```

Comment: This is going slow because you are using a loop. Why do you need a loop here??? You are performing 150 delete statements when you need one.

Comment: for the delete to occur, each record has to be locked if others are editing the records then the system has to wait.  since your looping it has to check every time for locked records.  If you delete in mass then the check occurs one time and once a lock is achieved on the entire set it can then delete.  thus instead of waiting for each day, it waits one time.

Answer (score 1):

Looping is horribly inefficient in sql server. It should be avoided except for a few administrative tasks or working with very large datasets. You might try replacing this loop based approach with something like this. I also changed the format of your date string literals so they are ANSI compliant and will work with any date format settings.

```
declare @StartDate date 
declare @EndDate date 

set @StartDate='2016-08-01'
set @EndDate='2016-12-30'

DELETE FROM [SAMPLEDB].[dbo].[MYTABLE]  
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, CREATE_DATE, 101) >= @StartDate
    AND CONVERT(DATE, CREATE_DATE, 101) <= @EndDate
```